# How did Ben get roughed up between S3:E4 and S3:E5 of Lupin?

Tags: continuity, lupin

In the [third season of *Lupin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupin_(French_TV_series)#Part_3_(2023)), Ben is arrested at the end of Episode Four. The police have him cornered, with no chance of escape. We don't see him actually being cuffed and taken away, but Ben's personality is not one that we would expect him to resist the arrest.

Later, we see him in Episode Five in prison, twice, and both times we see him, his face has recently taken a lot of damage, but has also had medical attention afterwards. Every time we see him for the rest of the season, his face is a bit more healed. It is obvious that *something* happened to him, but it is not clear what it was. I expect there was another scene that never made it past editing.

Was he hurt during his arrest? (unlikely given the scene)

Was he roughed up during an interrogation by the police? (Possible, but unlikely to have been done by Guédira, who is the only person we see interrogating him.)

Was he in a prison fight? (possible, to establish the premise that 'prison is a bad place')